# SQL Server: Having clause with variables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm working on a stored procedure for an academic institution that would allow advisors to filter their student lists by a number of criteria. Recently, the advisors asked me to give them the option of filtering students by GPA. This was perfectly easy until they asked for an option to determine the inequality.

Here's a truncated copy of the query I'm using, and the corresponding error message in SQL.

```
DECLARE @Inequality CHAR(2)
SET @Inequality = '>='

DECLARE @Gpa DECIMAL(3,1)
SET @Gpa = 2.0

SELECT DISTINCT
    mem.StudentID,
    SUM(GradePointValue * Credits) / SUM(Credits) AS GPA
FROM <snip>
WHERE <snip>
GROUP BY mem.StudentID
HAVING 
    CASE @Inequality
        WHEN '>=' THEN SUM(GradePointValue * Credits) / SUM(Credits) >= @Gpa
        WHEN '>'  THEN SUM(GradePointValue * Credits) / SUM(Credits) >  @Gpa
        WHEN '<'  THEN SUM(GradePointValue * Credits) / SUM(Credits) <  @Gpa
        WHEN '<=' THEN SUM(GradePointValue * Credits) / SUM(Credits) <= @Gpa
    END 
ORDER BY GPA desc
```

When I try to execute this query, SSMS gives me the following error message: `Incorrect syntax near '>'.`, referencing the first line of the `CASE` statement in the `HAVING` clause, `>= @GPA`

I've tried rewriting the `HAVING` clause to:

```
HAVING SUM(GradePointValue * Credits) / SUM(Credits)
    CASE @Inequality
        WHEN '>=' THEN >=
        ...
    END @Gpa
```

This produces another error message: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.`

I know I could copy and paste the entire SQL query four times and change only the inequality in the `HAVING` clause in each query, but that's messy (not that this isn't -- it just doesn't smell as bad to me) and I'd like to avoid it if I can. Is there any way for me to pull off my attempt above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
;WITH cte As
(
SELECT /*Don't need DISTINCT with GROUP BY*/
    mem.StudentID,
    SUM(GradePointValue * Credits) / SUM(Credits) AS GPA
FROM <snip>
WHERE <snip>
GROUP BY mem.StudentID
)
SELECT StudentID, GPA
FROM cte WHERE (GPA > @Gpa AND LEFT(@Inequality, 1) = '>')
            OR (GPA = @Gpa AND RIGHT(@Inequality,1) = '=')
            OR (GPA < @Gpa AND LEFT(@Inequality,1) = '<')
```

Comment: That worked incredibly well. Thanks! Now to document the HELL out of that WITH statement...

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try with -

```
CASE ''' + @Inequality + '''
```

Comment: That didn't change the error message in either of the above cases.

Comment: @jwiscarson - Well, then instead of using actual signs, can you set your @Inequality to some string which you can use in CASE. Something like "greaterThan", "LessThan" etc...

Comment: Still no luck. The issue isn't with the `CASE` statement accurately comparing `@Inequality` to the character strings in my `WHEN` keywords, but the inequalities themselves after the `THEN` keyword.

Comment: @jwiscarson - Just look at @Martin's answer. That seems to be something what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can mimic having multiple WHERE clauses with a CASE statement.

```
DECLARE
 @Inequality VARCHAR(2)
,@Gpa FLOAT
SET @Inequality = '>='
SET @Gpa = 2.0


SELECT
 V.StudentID
,V.GPA

FROM (
    SELECT
     mem.StudentID
    ,SUM(GradePointValue * Credits)/SUM(Credits) AS GpaValue

    FROM <snip>

    WHERE <snip>

    GROUP BY mem.StudentID
) AS V

WHERE CASE WHEN @Inequality = '>=' AND V.GpaValue >= @Gpa THEN 1
        WHEN @Inequality = '>' AND V.GpaValue > @Gpa THEN 1
        WHEN @Inequality = '<' AND V.GpaValue < @Gpa THEN 1
        WHEN @Inequality = '<=' AND V.GpaValue <= @Gpa THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END = 1
```

You could also do this if you don't want an inline view.

```
SELECT
 mem.StudentID
,SUM(GradePointValue * Credits)/SUM(Credits) AS GpaValue

FROM <snip>

WHERE <snip>

GROUP BY mem.StudentID

HAVING CASE WHEN @Inequality = '>=' AND SUM(GradePointValue * Credits)/SUM(Credits) >= @Gpa THEN 1
        WHEN @Inequality = '>' AND SUM(GradePointValue * Credits)/SUM(Credits) > @Gpa THEN 1
        WHEN @Inequality = '<' AND SUM(GradePointValue * Credits)/SUM(Credits) < @Gpa THEN 1
        WHEN @Inequality = '<=' AND SUM(GradePointValue * Credits)/SUM(Credits) <= @Gpa THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting your `SUM(GradePointValue * Credits) / SUM(Credits)` to a `DECIMAL`.

Comment: SQL Server's already casting the result to a decimal -- the having clause worked fine when I had it statically set to `SUM(GradePointValue * Credits) / SUM(Credits) < @Gpa`